# Finding the Power Series of a Complex fuction.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find a power series expression $\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n z^n $ for $ \frac{1}{z^2-\sqrt2 z +2} $

I'm completely stuck on this question.  I know how to manipulate power series but I've never had to find one from such a complicated function.  Also we're asked to find the radius of convergence although this I think I can do.  Also I know that maybe the Taylor series expansion could help but differentiating that function leads to an awful mess.

Answer (score 3):

$$
z^2-\sqrt{2}\,z+2=(z-a)(z-b)\text{ where }a=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6\,i}{2},\ b=\frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt6\,i}{2}.
$$
Use partial fraction decomposition to write
$$
\frac{1}{z^2-\sqrt{2}\,z+2}=\frac{A}{z-a}+\frac{B}{z-b}.
$$
Now expand in power series $1/(z-a)$ and $1/(z-b)$.